# Sequence regarding multiples

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

I came through this sequence.

> $\ a_{n}$ is a sequence with all terms integers. $a_1=15$, and when $n \geq2$, $a_n$ is the smallest non-negative integer such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ is a multiple of $n$.

I couldn't find a general equation for the nth term, so I wrote some terms.
$$a_1=15, a_2=1, a_3=2, a_4=2, a_5=0, a_6=4, a_7=4, a_8=4, a_9=4, a_{10}=4...$$
So I figured out that there are a lot of 4's after $n=6$, and I think the sequence will have $a_n=4$ for all $n \geq6$. But I can't figure out the mathematical proof for this relation. I figure this has to do something with elementary number theory. Also, is there a name for this recurrence relation?

Comment: Note $3(n+1)<4n<4(n+1)$ and induct.

Comment: @user10354138 oh... I kind of think I get it. So $S_n=4n$ for $n \geq6$..right? And I can prove this by the relation you wrote above?

Comment: Yes, in fact $S_5=20=4\times 5$ too.

Comment: @user10354138 oh..it was actually a somewhat obvious question, thanks for helping me out.